# Mailgun email sending not working! Laravel 7 app deployed on Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-7, mailgun

I configured `Mailgun` for my Heroku application from the command line, so Heroku added the env. variables to the Heroku settings and I get the following error:

```
Client error: `POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxfa4b1f9bc0414e2e977ba9e87270ecb2.mailgun.org/messages.mime` resulted in a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` response:
Forbidden
```

Comment: Did you also include your api token in the request?

Comment: Asa far as I know the Mailable Laravel class automatically handles this. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, it handles but did you enter it somewhere because without it you cannot make a valid request.

Comment: Yes, It was added as a Heroku environment variable to the Heroku Settings.